# How to Change a explode field in db with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, pdo

i have a two table

1- 
myusers:
id
name
...

2-
mygroup
id
idusers

and idusers impload idusers with , !

### example : id1,id2,id3

i want check all mygroup Field And Delete id no exist in myuser

please Help me

Comment: did u tried anything? plz share

Comment: i haven't any idea For this Task :(

Comment: u must need to share the both table structure

Comment: JUST table1:Myuser : id AND table2:mygroup:id,idusers

Answer (score 0):

Please Use "FIND_IN_SET" mysql that will find value in comma separated value.

For more detail you can find below link 
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

Comment: Can you SEND a Code For my tables?